# NSPredicate into deep filtering values

Tags: ios, search, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have following list of multiple data and i want to filter out persons who are male 
    using NSPredicate how can i do it

```
[
  "Human": {
    "Person": {
      "isMale": true,
      "name": "PersonA",
      "id": "100"
    },
    "isCheck": true
  },
  "Human": {
    "Person": {
      "isMale": false,
      "name": "PersonB",
      "id": "200"
    },
    "isCheck": false
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
]
```

An array contains dictionaries and each dictionary contains a single person dictionary and i want to filter out on inner dictionary person key.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like JSON. Have you already converted it to NSArray?

Comment: yes i already converted it into array

Comment: The JSON you provided is not valid one. Can you check it?

Answer (score 4):

[Wain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16807254/767730) would work fine.

Try this code snippet which uses a json file formed from your question.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Humans" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *users = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Human.Person.isMale == %@",@true];

NSArray *filteredArray = [users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",filteredArray);
```

[Humans.json](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/General/Humans.json) file

Comment: can you a format for json in which there is a subArray in Preson and we need a filter over there?

Answer (score 2):

In your predicate you need to use `Person.isMale` because you need to navigate to the inner dictionary.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Person.isMale == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Comment: No... i am unable to get result.

Comment: Apart from the unmatched parenthesis in the predicate this looks like the correct solution.

Comment: @AJG Why is this not working? I tried it and found to be working.

Comment: it is giving me crash with following error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< Human 0x6e60680> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Person.' is there any problem ?

Comment: Can you add the actual array to the question rather than JSON please. You need to know the correct key path to use.

Comment: @AJG: What is the `Human` class? Do you use NSJSONSerialization to convert the JSON to an array or something else that creates custom objects?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked **[KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)** ?

**Try This :**

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Human.Person.isMale == 1)"];
```

Comment: this is like traversing whole array ...... can i do the same thing by using NSPredicate?

Comment: it is giving me crash with following error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< Human 0x6e60680> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Person.' is there any problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *valueString = @"true"

NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id       evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

 if([[[[evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"Human"] objectForKey:@"Person"] objectForKey:@"isMale"] isEqualToString:valueString])
                return YES;

            return NO;

        }];

NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isMale == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool:(BOOL)true]];
```

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isMale == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]] I tried this one ..... but i am unable to get result